# Airflow: Scheduling a task multiple times a day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I take input from the user about the schedule of the tasks. I want to run the task multiple times a day. How is it possible using Airflow?

Comment: Can the user pick different times? is a free form or are you giving a fixed list of options to pick? Maybe a screenshot could help to understand your problem.

Comment: @skozz, User is free to choose any five time entries.

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule a DAG to run multiple times a day by using the `schedule_interval` arg in your DAG like so:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='fake_dag',
    schedule_interval="* * * * *"
    )
```

`schedule_interval` uses CRON format. This may help you understand [CRON format](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm).

Example: if you want your DAG to run every 4 hours during a day, your DAG would look like below:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='fake_dag',
    schedule_interval="* 0-23/4 * * *"
    )
```

Comment: Wouldn't this run the dag every minute for every 4 hours?

Comment: @Bigmoose70 Haha yeah you are correct! `0 0-23/4 * * *` is probably more accurate to the example I was going for.